# Unable to activate instance of type Android.Util.SparseArray`1[E] from native handle 0x15 (key_handle 0x98855da)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am just get stuck of this problem.

In xamarin.Android I am getting this is error in ReceiveDetections method.

here is the error:

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'Unable to activate instance of type Android.Util.SparseArray`1[E] from native handle 0x15 (key_handle 0x98855da).'
```

Before it was working I'm getting this error after upgrading the android version.

Here is the snippet:

```
 public void ReceiveDetections(Detections detections)
    {
        SparseArray qrcodes = detections.DetectedItems;  // getting the error here

        if (qrcodes.Size() != 0)
        {
            //////////////////////////////                
        }
        
    }
```

I am getting this problem in debug mode.

Comment: It will be fixed in the new Preview version of Xamarin.Android or you could downgrade to Xamarin.Android to V10.2.xx.You could refer [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/4795).

Answer (score 0):

According to the Visual Studio [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1050379/unable-to-activate-instance-of-type-androidutilspa.html), try to

- Clear temporary bin and obj files
- Update to the latest version of VS
- Disable Android Share Runtime
- Build the app in release mode, or
- Increase the Target Framework version of the Android project to 10 or above

Let me know if neither of those solve your issue

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. First 3 didn't work for me.
I face this problem while running debug mode not release mode.
would it be any problem if i increase the target framework?
will it run in lower version device if i increase it?

Comment: That’s great!!! :) just look at the android project options and compare what configurations are different between the two - shrinker, linker, etc and isolate exactly which option is causing the issue. Then make that config changes in your debug configuration.